# How do we query the college score card and just get all data but only for a given year?

Tags: data.gov, collegescorecard

When querying the college score card, data for all years are returned, how do I query to return all data for a given year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying the API, you can download the raw CSVs for each year: [CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip](https://ed-public-download.apps.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip). There are occasional variables with all missing values that you may need API calls to fill in, however.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can ask for all data for one year but you could ask for certain fields for a given year using this query:

```
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?_fields=id,school.name,2013.student.size,2013.earnings.8_yrs_after_entry.90th_percentile_earnings&api_key=XXXX
```